# javascript animation causes maximum stack error

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I think I just need a second pair of eyes, but for some reason these two animations being called, one after the other, causes an infinite loop, and I can't seem to figure out why. The first animation (tongueAnimation) is supposed to run 6 times and merely swaps out map marker icon images where the images names are hungry1, hungry2, hungry3... to correspond to the runcount variable. Then the second animation (handAnimation) does the same thing, but only toggles between two images. I tried to comment the code as best as I could.

```
var runcount = 2;

function tongueAnimation() {
    //if animation has run six or less icon image swaps
    if (runcount < 7) {
        moveTongue();
    }
    else {
        //runcount gets set to 1 for counting handAnimation which will now be called
        runcount = 1;
        handAnimation();
    }
}

//sets the icon image for the marker
function moveTongue() {
    //images are named hungry1, hungry2 ... so the count decides which image name will be used
    orderMarker.icon = "images/hungry" + runcount + ".png";
    //count that fact that moveTongue has been called
    runcount++;
    //call the function that invokeded this one
    setTimeout(tongueAnimation(), 150);
}

function handAnimation() {
    //if animation has run six or less icon image swaps
    if (runcount < 7) {
        moveHands();
    }
    //else reset runcount to original value of 2 and start over by calling tongueAnimation after three seconds
    else {
        runcount = 2;
        setTimeout(tongueAnimation(), 3000);
    }
}

function moveHands() {
    if (orderMarker.icon != "images/hungryDown.png") {
        orderMarker.icon = "images/hungryDown.png"
    }
    else {
        orderMarker.icon = "images/hungry1.png"
    }
    runcount++;
    setTimeout(handAnimation(), 250);
```

}

Comment: You're *calling* `tongueAnimation()` (and `handAnimation()`) instead of *passing* these functions to `setTimeout()`. They end up running synchronously and smashing your stack.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. moveTongue() and moveHands() are being called without setTimeout. tongueAnimation() and handAnimation() are being called within setTimeout. There is only an initial call to TongueAnimation() in document.ready(). All other calls to tongueAnimation() are through setTimeout

Comment: Nope, they aren't. `setTimeout(foo, delay)` calls `foo()` asynchronously ("within" `setTimeout()`). `setTimeout(foo(), delay)` calls `foo()` synchronously *right now* and passes *the value it returns* (`undefined`) to `setTimeout()`. Do you see the difference?

Comment: Unfortunately, not really. My apologies. As far as I see, handAnimation() can only be called by tongueAnimation(), and it calls it when it is done with its animation, and that's why handAnimation is not initially called within a setTimeout. But it is recalled by moveHands within a setTimeout.

Comment: Please read my last comment again, focusing on the call operators (the parentheses pairs `()`) in your invocations of `setTimeout()`. If you do that right, you should soon be enlightened.

Comment: oh, you don't actually call the function when using set timeout, you merely reference the function name, hence no parans should be included. Let me try that and if it works, add it as an answer and I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: I think that's the right answer, and it no longer blows the stack away, even though it still doesn't run like I want, but that's due to other things. But you found that particular problem, so if you add it as an answer I can mark it accepted. Thanks.